# Can you access monthly used execution time in a lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an android app that uses AWS lambda as a backend to fetch data - which usually takes a few seconds of execution time per request.

I would like to be able to fetch data and cache it at the end of the month if there is still free execution time available, however, I could not find a way to access that information inside a lambda function. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if there is still free execution time available

You cannot directly do that, need to perform cloudwatch log aggregation as told by @Dan M, but the most ideal way would be to always set an alarm and notification once your overall execution time( across all functions ) exceeds your desired value

It is a very straightforward approach using `cloudwatch alarms` :-

- You need to choose metric based on dimension which is called as `across all functions` to be able to view  aggregated execution time for all functions in that region. [Check how to view all functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-metrics.html#monitoring-metrics-console)
- There are 2 types of metrics `Invocation` and `performance metrics`, you need to focus on performance metrics, for these metrics you need to consider their average statistic
- Now create cloudwatch alarm for `Duration metric` ( under performance metric) and add sns rule when ever alarm breaches your desired value

According to [Docs for duration metric](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-metrics.html#monitoring-metrics-types)

> The amount of time that your function code spends processing an event. The billed duration for an invocation is the value of Duration rounded up to the nearest millisecond.

[Docs for creating cloud watch alarm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ConsoleAlarms.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your Lambda function send logs to Cloudwatch. Then, whenever it executes, you get something like:

```
REPORT RequestId: c9999f19-0b99-4996-8dea-94c9999999de  Duration: 5495.59 ms    Billed Duration: 5496 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 82 MB  Init Duration: 306.78 ms
```

You can then export the logs and using whatever tool you like get your monthly total.